# How to promote a heterogeneous array (Array{Any}) to a homogeneous array with elements of a single common type?

Tags: julia

Imagine that, for example, one has a heterogeneous array like

```
julia> a = {1, 2.2, int32(3), float32(4.4), 5, 6.6}
6-element Array{Any,1}:
 1  
 2.2
 3  
 4.4
 5  
 6.6
```

for which the single common type of its elements is `Float64`.

Is there a function or minimalistic command to convert such `Any` arrays to arrays of elements with a single common type (`Array{Float64}` for the given example) without having to explicitly write that type or even know it beforehand?

I know that if the brackets `[]` were used to create the array, one would obtain an `Array{Float64}` in the first place. However, the question is about the conversion of arrays whose type one cannot control at creation time (e.g., some array comprehensions, arrays read from files, ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are looking for to convert types is called `convert`

```
julia> a = {1, 2.2, int32(3), float32(4.4), 5, 6.6}
f6-element Array{Any,1}:
 1  
 2.2
 3  
 4.4
 5  
 6.6

julia> convert(Array{Float64,1},a)
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.2
 3.0
 4.4
 5.0
 6.6
```

**EDIT:**
I'm not sure I understand your *why* you would want the behaviour you are asking for, but i would think the solution to the question you ask (not the problem you have!), is:

```
[promote(a...)...]
```

Comment: Thanks @ivarne, but I don't want to have to explicitly write the type, or even know beforehand which is the single common type. For the example I gave the common type is more or less obvious, however I'm asking about something generic which works for any heterogeneous array (even when the single common type is `Any` itself).

Comment: Great! That's what I was asking for ;)

Comment: About the problem: for example, sometimes one has type unsafe functions which when used inside array comprehensions entail heterogeneous arrays as result. Those issues only arise in more complex situations, but you can get the idea from this minimal example: `[randn()>0 ? 1 : 2.0  for _ in 1:10]` (which, I know, admit simpler solutions).

Comment: You can make the array comprehension make a homogeneous array of a given type like so `Float64[randn()>0 ? 1 : 2.0  for _ in 1:10]`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
reshape([a...],size(a)...)
```

If you're happy with a Vector, you can use simply:

```
[a...]
```

Comment: Yes, I like `[a...]`. It calls `vcat`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that `vcat(a...)` also works.

However I think @ivarne's solution is preferable, since it explicitly tells what one wants to do.

On the other hand, `convert(a...)` does not works if it's not defined for the array element types.